# Docusign programmatically get completed document as soon as its complete

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the API and my workflow is this:

Create envelope with one embedded signer (route order 1) and one email signer (route order 2). The embedded signer is signing the document and at that point an email is triggered to the second signer to go review and sign the document.

Now I can retrieve the document when the first user has completed the signing process but how can I do this for the second one?

I want to be able to get the completed document programmatically as soon as the second signer completes it.

**Question**: Is there any way of achieving that without having to poll for completed envelopes from a scheduled task (i.e. a cron event)?

Or in other words is there any action that can trigger the retrieval of a completed document?

**Subquestion**: Is it possible to control the return url of the email signer so that I can create the appropriate action there? Or even better can I change the default email link to point to a page in my website?

Comment: Re: question 1: DocuSign connect can be used to provide you push notifications for several different types of envelope/signer events - https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect.  Re subquestion: You can specify landing pages (URL's) that the user gets re-directed to on various events, such as signing complete or decline. The admin guide includes information on this as does https://www.docusign.com/support/new/documentation/ndse-help/branding

Comment: @LuisScott I gues that will do. Put it up as an answer for me to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: question 1: DocuSign connect can be used to provide you push notifications for several different types of envelope/signer events - docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect.

Re subquestion: You can specify landing pages (URL's) that the user gets re-directed to on various events, such as signing complete or decline. The admin guide includes information on this as does docusign.com/support/new/documentation/ndse-help/branding